# How to implement 'pop up box' in Android similar to Viber (when a message is received)

Tags: android, dialog, broadcastreceiver, android-view

I work as a junior Android developer and the client has requested the following:

"Make research about implementation of pop up box, while application is in background. Thea idea is always when there is notification to show in notification panel, also to be shown in pop up box." (Viber was taken as an example of this)

I know how to work with activities and fragments and views in Android, but I don't know how to even google about this so I thought someone could point out a tutorial or just say if there is a word for this technique so I can study it. When a new message is received (Broadcast Receivers) the 'pop up box' is shown on top of the Android system. My question would be what is the pattern and what are the key pointss in implementing this feature. Thank you in advance

[image: The pop up box should appear same as viber new message box.]

Comment: I'm looking for same too...

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, possible way is to implement pop-up as an activity with transparent background. Here is the starting point: [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple.

You just create `Activity` extends `Dialog` type.

So your activity type should show as image in above - the activity dialog.