# Notification pop up in home screen like viber in android

Tags: android

I want show Viber like home screen pop up when Push notification received by my application, I google it but did not get the answer. My requirement is like this [How to implement 'pop up box' in Android similar to Viber (when a message is received)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174411/how-to-implement-pop-up-box-in-android-similar-to-viber-when-a-message-is-rec)

Comment: You should at least have searched some possible options, even if partial solutions. This is a very broad question.

Comment: I answered that question http://stackoverflow.com/a/25325550/317928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I am answering to question as I got solution.

In GCMIntentService Class

while creating intent add the following code to show the Intent as Viber does.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

This will show the intent immediately irrespective to the App State.
Thanks

Comment: This answer mean it will create new activity. could you put the code notifications pop up? thanks.